# Postman not working for PaymentsOS (Authorization not working)

Tags: postman, payment-gateway, payment, rest

I tried using paymentsOs in postman and i intend to create authorization. However, i get errors and cannot seem to find out what is the issue here?

Here is my code and the error i got
[Problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmzKX.jpg)

Comment: Follow the document,  you'd find why it gives an error of bad request

Comment: The api is working fine since it is getting you the error response. Either your app_id, private_key or other header parameter is incorrect or the url needs a query string.